# Reading multiple JSON Object's text as an each jQuery statement?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Suppose I have some JSON in the form of variable a:

```
{"definitions":[
    {"text":"An internet search, such as that which is performed on the Google search engine.","attribution":"from Wiktionary, Creative Commons Attribution/Share-Alike License"},
    {"text":"A match obtained by a query in the Google search engine.","attribution":"from Wiktionary, Creative Commons Attribution/Share-Alike License"},
    {"text":"To search for (something) on the Internet using the Google search engine.","attribution":"from Wiktionary, Creative Commons Attribution/Share-Alike License"},
    {"text":"To search for (something) on the Internet using any comprehensive search engine.","attribution":"from Wiktionary, Creative Commons Attribution/Share-Alike License"},
    {"text":"To be locatable in a search of the Internet.","attribution":"from Wiktionary, Creative Commons Attribution/Share-Alike License"},
    {"text":"To deliver googlies.","attribution":"from Wiktionary, Creative Commons Attribution/Share-Alike License"},
    {"text":"To move as a ball in a googly.","attribution":"from Wiktionary, Creative Commons Attribution/Share-Alike License"}
]}
```

Here is the each statement

```
var qr="";
jQuery.each(a.definitions, function(i,val) {
    qr +="<li>"+ val + "</li>";
});
$('#someDIV p').replaceWith(qr);
```

I am trying to display the text definitions in the form of a list of definitions like:

An internet search, such as that which is performed on the Google search engine.

A match obtained by a query in the Google search engine.

et cetera

But when I use the jQuery.each(a.definition) in jQuery it gives me

```
<li>[object Object]</li>
<li>[object Object]</li>
<li>[object Object]</li>
<li>[object Object]</li>
<li>[object Object]</li>
<li>[object Object]</li>
<li>[object Object]</li>
```

How do I read the object's text (which is the definition) so that it gives me the definition not [object Object] something like how

```
jQuery.each(a.definitions[0], function(i,val) {
    qr +="<li>"+ val + "</li>";
});
```

gives me the first definition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `.text` will give you this attribute of the **Object**.

```
jQuery.each(a.definitions, function(i, val) {
    qr += '<li>' + val.text + '</li>';
});
```

If you want to show the index of the object you can use `i` something like this:

```
qr += '<li>Index:' + i + ': ' + val.text + '</li>';
```

Comment: Good suggestion to include the index.

Answer (score 1):

Your definitions are comprised of an array of objects that need to be further parsed. Use `val.text` to see the description text. It can also be helpful to use the console to view the actual output of loop while it's happening. Wrap the variable in `console.log(variable)` and the console will show you everything there is to know about `val`.

```
jQuery.each(a.definitions[0], function(i,val) {
    console.log(val);
    qr +="<li>"+ val.text + "</li>";
});
```

Comment: Good suggestion to use `console.log`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to display the `text` property of each on of the entries:

```
jQuery.each(a.definitions, function(i, val) {
    qr += '<li>' + val.text + '</li>';
});
```

You can also display the attribution by using `val.attribution`.

Documentation for [`jQuery.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) on [api.jquery.com](http://api.jquery.com).

---

**Explanation for your Error**

You are getting `[object Object]` because you are actually `toString()`ing the object rather than the text contained in the `text` property of the object.

I have formatted the JSON below to make it easier to explain:

```
{
    "definitions": [{
        "text": "An internet search, such as that which is performed on the Google search engine.",
        "attribution": "from Wiktionary, Creative Commons Attribution/Share-Alike License"
    }, {
        "text": "A match obtained by a query in the Google search engine.",
        "attribution": "from Wiktionary, Creative Commons Attribution/Share-Alike License"
    }, {
        "text": "To search for (something) on the Internet using the Google search engine.",
        "attribution": "from Wiktionary, Creative Commons Attribution/Share-Alike License"
    }, {
        "text": "To search for (something) on the Internet using any comprehensive search engine.",
        "attribution": "from Wiktionary, Creative Commons Attribution/Share-Alike License"
    }, {
        "text": "To be locatable in a search of the Internet.",
        "attribution": "from Wiktionary, Creative Commons Attribution/Share-Alike License"
    }, {
        "text": "To deliver googlies.",
        "attribution":"from Wiktionary, Creative Commons Attribution/Share-Alike License"
    }, {
        "text": "To move as a ball in a googly.",
        "attribution": "from Wiktionary, Creative Commons Attribution/Share-Alike License"
    }]
}
```

I'd like to point out that as you iterate the `a.definitions` array, each of the `val`s you receive in the `each` function's callback is an object that looks something like this:

```
{
    "text": "To be locatable in a search of the Internet.",
    "attribution": "from Wiktionary, Creative Commons Attribution/Share-Alike License"
}
```

therefore you must access the properties individually as in the code I provided above.